# Primefaces Push: WebSocket to Long-Polling unexpected

Tags: amazon-ec2, primefaces, push, atmosphere

I have a web application based on Prime Push with below detail

1. > = Tomcat 7.0x75
2. > = Primfaces 6.x
3. Amazon EC2

Currently I do see the Long-Polling being used instead of Web-Socket. Do you know what reason behind why Web-Socket is not used and downgrade to Long-Polling?

Note: It was used to work but now it stopped working which I can't find out the root cause.

Please let me know if you need any information.

Thanks,
Nghia

Comment: what changed between 'working' and 'noy working

Comment: That is also a question for me. I totally forgot what the change which we changed from Amazon EC2.  From application we dont have anything change